# npm install not works - `node-gyp rebuild` error

Tags: node.js

I had the error bellow when I was preparing my blockchaine developmement environement :

My environment was under:

- NodeJs 10.15.3 LTS.
- npm 8.x

npm install not works - `node-gyp rebuild` error

This an extract of the output error:

no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘Nan::imp::NativeGetter {aka void (*)(v8::Local, const v8::PropertyCallbackInfo&)}’ to ‘v8::Local’ x509.target.mk:106: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/x509/src/addon.o' failed

and this is the screenshot's error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPQGo.png)

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to downgrade nodeJS to 8.15.1

- nvm install 8.15.1

Good luck